# How to inherit class in SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to convert my Swift App into SwiftUI. In My Swift App I am having one listener class inheriting in home class. In that home class one function is calling. (Home is Viewcontroller class)

I am trying to do same in SwiftUI but as SwiftUI View is struct can't do that.

Sharing my Swift Code

```
extension Home: Listener {
    func event(_ event: Event) {
        if event == HomeEvent.check{
            if let response = event as? CheckG {
                handleCheck(response)
            }
        }
}

public protocol Listener: class {
    func event(_ event: Event)
}
```

In SwiftUI

```
struct Home: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack() {
            Text("Home")
        }
 }
```

My question might be wrong as I am new to iOS ..Request you to guide on my query.

Thank You for help

Comment: "Home is Viewcontroller class" you shouldn't have the same name for a class and struct

Comment: @aheze Thanks for reply but my Swift and SwiftUI are two diff app.

Comment: `structs` do not have inheritance. Classes do exist with SwiftUI. You should really run through some tutorials first to understand SwiftUI. Past that we can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).